# iOS issue while unzip file using ZipArchive?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, php-ziparchive, ziparchive-objectivec

I am performing a task in which I have to zip a PDF file which is store in a document directory and then unzip the file. I am facing issue while unzipping the file, maybe I am not doing at correct location because when I print the  location on console and navigate to that location I can see the file.

But while trying the file on that location I am getting error "the operation couldn't be completed no such file or directory".

Following is my code: in which I am decoding a base64 string into zip at a location.

```
NSData *plainTextData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:base64StringReceivedFromServer];

NSString *docsDir;

NSArray *dirPaths;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *databasePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"demo.zip"];

NSString *absoluteFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",databasePath];

[plainTextData writeToFile:absoluteFilePath atomically:YES];
```

2) trying to unzip the file:

```
NSString *test;

NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) 

objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *zipFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"demo.zip"];

NSString *absoluteFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",zipFilePath];

NSString *targetDirPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NILESHFOLDER"];

ZipArchive* zipArchive = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];

if( [zipArchive UnzipOpenFile:absoluteFilePath] )    
{
    if( [zipArchive UnzipFileTo:targetDirPath overWrite:YES] != NO )
    {
    }
    [zipArchive UnzipCloseFile]; 
 }
```

I think I am not able to write the zip into correct location

Comment: Does the `NILESHFOLDER` Folder is there ?

Comment: yes its there,even i can see the zip file into it.

Comment: but not able to unzip it